# Where future rows don't exist

Tags: mysql-5.5

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE TaskJournal (
  TaskJournalId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  TaskId INT NOT NULL,
  TaskStatus TINYINT NOT NULL,
  TaskStart INT NOT NULL,
  TaskEnd INT NULL,
  TaskInfo TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (TaskJournalId)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO TaskJournal (TaskId, TaskStatus, TaskStart, TaskEnd, TaskInfo) 
VALUES (2, 1, 1533660028, 1533660500, "No issues present"),
(3, 3, 1533660505, 1533660506, "Exception found: Line 95"),
(2, 1, 1533660015, 1533660018, "No issues present"),
(2, 3, 1533660509, 1533660512, "Exception found: Line 95"),
(2, 1, 1533660515, 1533660530, "No issues present");
```

The problem is this, I want to gather a list of errors but only if at a future time there is no resolution.

Ideally I'd get something like this back

```
| TaskJournalId | TaskId | TaskStatus | TaskStart  | TaskEnd    | TaskInfo          |
| 3             | 2      | 1          | 1533660015 | 1533660018 | No issues present |
```

Only because in the future there isn't some TaskId that has the exception present.

So I thought I could do this via group of sub queries something like as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TaskJournal 
WHERE TaskId = 2 
GROUP BY TaskId, TaskStatus 
HAVING TaskStatus=3 
ORDER BY TaskStart DESC
```

But the problem with this is that it returns both rows 4 and 2 (chronological descending order). But at some later point there appears to have been a resolution to TaskId=2 but not for TaskId=3.

Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this wasn't nearly as complicated as I thought, at least when I took a step back and looked at the problem again. Below is the query I came up with (and a few minor flourishes to enhance the output).

```
  SELECT TaskJournalId, 
         TaskId, 
         TaskStatus, 
         FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(TaskStart)) AS LastRun, 
         FROM_UNIXTIME(TaskEnd) AS TaskEnd,
         CASE
             WHEN (LENGTH(MAX(TaskInfo)) = LENGTH('No issues present')) THEN 'OK'
             ELSE CONCAT('FAIL:', SUBSTR(MAX(TaskInfo), 17, LENGTH(MAX(TaskInfo)))) 
         END AS TaskInfo
    FROM TaskJournal
GROUP BY TaskId
ORDER BY TaskId;
```

Answer (score 1):

## MySQL-5.5

Bummer.

It appears Analytical Functions are not supported in v5.5

If it did, the solution would be something like:

```
select TaskJournalId, TaskId, TaskStatus, TaskStart, TaskEnd, TaskInfo
from (
  select  TaskJournalId, TaskId, TaskStatus, TaskStart, TaskEnd, TaskInfo
    ,row_number() over (partition by TaskJournalId,TaskId order by TaskStart DESC) rn
  from TaskJournal
)
where TaskStatus=3 and rn=1;
```

## My Answer

Upgrade your database.

Comment: Actually I did partially go with this solution, I am having the db servers upgraded to accommodate the extra functionality that I may require.

Answer (score 1):

Look like you want to get the list of issues for each `TaskId` that follows the last occurence of the `No issues present` or exactly the string `No issues present` if that list is empty for certain `TaskId`. The special case if there is no single `No issues present` but there is some errors for certain `TaskId`.

```
SELECT IFNULL( q.TaskJournalId, x.TaskJournalId ) AS TaskJournalId
       IFNULL( q.TaskId, x.TaskId )               AS TaskId
       IFNULL( q.TaskStatus, x.TaskStatus )       AS TaskStatus
       IFNULL( q.TaskStart, x.TaskStart )         AS TaskStart 
       IFNULL( q.TaskEnd, x.TaskEnd )             AS TaskEnd
       IFNULL( q.TaskInfo, x.TaskInfo )           AS TaskInfo

  FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT TaskId 
           FROM TaskJournal 
       ) AS z

  LEFT JOIN ( SELECT TaskId, MAX(TaskStart) AS maxTS
                FROM TaskJournal 
               WHERE TaskInfo = 'No issues present'
               GROUP BY TaskId
            ) AS w
         ON w.TaskId = z.TaskId

  JOIN TaskJournal  AS x 
         ON x.TaskId = z.TaskId
        AND x.TaskStart = w.maxTS

  LEFT JOIN TaskJournal AS q 
         ON q.TaskId = z.TaskId
        AND ( q.TaskStart > w.maxTS OR w.maxTS IS NULL ) 
;
```